# Builder used same brand for lights and fan in 3 different places

Tags: lighting, fans

The builder who built my house and a few other houses near me had put in a [hampton bay brand ligh](http://hamptonbayoutlet.com/)t and fan in my master room, my family room, and my neighbors family room.  It is not necessarily the exact same model but it is from the hampton bay family brand.  The remotes are almost identical.

Whenever I use the remote for one of the rooms it turns on / off the fan / lights in the other rooms..including my neighbors.  The other day we were sleeping with a dim light and a fan running.  Suddenly the light was increased freaking us out!  When we turned it off the same thing happened.  This went off and on for like 5 minutes.  The next morning the neighbor called us and mentioned it had happened to her.  Come to find out she was turning hers on and during that same time she was turning ours on as well.  Me turning ours off turned hers off as well...

Same issue with my family room fan and light.  When I turn it on upstairs in my master bedroom it also turns it on in our family room.  Its not a huge issue because the actual light switch has to be turned on to activate whether the fan / light can be controlled via the remote or not.

I just hate it since it causes issues with my other room and my neighbor.  What can I do ?

Comment: @HenryJackson - That sort of helps but the main issue is its in the same house...meaning my master bedroom is simply above our family room...I cannot seem to change the frequency as it still interfers.

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in that answer? The remote and the fan need to be set to the same frequency. So you can change the switches in one room to match each other, and in the other room to a different setting. I assume all 3 fans in question are now set to the same frequency which is why they are responding to each other's remotes.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the frequency IS the answer, regardless of the location of the fan. A remote with a new battery could easily work to a house next door.

Some remotes/receivers use DIP switches. They are tiny little switches in a row, usually four of them, and you change the combinations of on/off so that the receiver and the remote match.

Others use an RF signal where you typically press and hold a button 'till an LED lights up, then press another button so that the two are paired.

You really need the instructions to let you know what method your fans use to change the frequency.